# Could-not create the view: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView

Tags: android

I am new to Android and building a small test program and the program is not running and giving me Could not create the view: org.eclipse.pde.runtime.LogView error

here is the code from my android_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java code from MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize that I am posting this as an answer instead of a comment, but commenting requires 50 reputation and I don't have that yet.  Can you post your java code too?  The problem is likely in there, it may be the method by which you are loading the view.

Comment: Cool, I can comment to my answers, so that's good :)  What API level is this running?  And also which JDK version?

Comment: How do i know what API level is it running?

Comment: The reason I ask is that you may want to try some combination of API 19 and/or JDK 1.7.  Give it a try and see if that helps.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, right-click on the project, select properties, then select Android.  You'll see a list of build targets, the one that is checked is the one you are using.  The API level is listed for it in that table.

Comment: Try changing the API level to 19.  Also, if you are using JDK 1.6, try using JDK 1.7 instead.  If you need more information on how to do that let me know, I'll add it to the answer instead of more comments :)